# Can't See MongoDB MessageProcessors in Mule Studio

Tags: mongodb, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to use the MongoDB Component to run a command on a Mongo database, but I can't find it in Mule Studio 3.4.0. The following page "http://mulesoft.github.io/mongo-connector/mule/mongo-config.html" lists all of the capabilities that I expect in the MongoDB Component, but I can't find them. What do I need to do to see them?

[image: Mule Mongo Component Features]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connector's operations are available in the properties pane of the `Mongo DB` **Cloud Connector** element, in your flow editor, not in the **Transformer** element as you are showing above.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have already done an update. I have version 3.4 of this plugin, but this repository has only version 2.2.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Reviewed my answer.